# unix find the difference from a file row wise

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have some data like

```
[09359]0000.365604|  =>SttSasph_Hmbm_bSPO_PhQmOm (Hmbm_PhQmOm_utWmP.asp)
[09359]0000.365687|  =>Hmbm_bSPO_PhQmOm_Wd (Hmbm_PhQmOm_utWmP.asp)
[09359]0000.365879|  =>SttSasph_Hmbm_quOuO_PhQmOm (Hmbm_PhQmOm_utWmP.asp)
[09359]0000.365890|  =>Hmbm_quOuO_PhQmOm_Wd (Hmbm_PhQmOm_utWmP.asp)
[09359]0000.365979|  WSmmOT SDDQ vSQWSbmO not POt, QOvOQtWnH to Onv mOthod
[09359]0001.625300|  db_HOt_POPPWon_Wd: aspuQQOnt POPPWon WD WP 1016,59
[09359]0002.365979|  WSmmOT SDDQ vSQWSbmO not POt, QOvOQtWnH to Onv mOthod
```

Every Line starts with a process number (Which can change) in square brackets

Then Seconds after the module (0001) in this case

Then MicroSeconds  after the fullstop.

Then a Pipe to terminate.

Rest part can be ignored

What I need is to caluclate

1. Convert Seconds into MircoSeconds
2. Add the Microsconds to Converted Microseconds (From 1)
3. Find out the difference in microseconds. for eg. line2-line1 , line3-line2, line4- line3 and so.
4. Print the result in seperate file.

I tried to use this logic. But, it didnt work. 
May I get suggestions with optimised way to do it or 
improvement in my existing logic

```
sec=$(grep '^\[.\{1,\}\]' mass.May28.1 | cut -d "|  " -f1 | cut -c8- | cut -d"." -f1)    
msec=$(grep '^\[.\{1,\}\]' mass.May28.1 | cut -d "|  " -f1 | cut -c8- | cut -d"." -f2)    
$f_msec=$((sec * 1000000 + msec)) > final_difference_file
```

Comment: What tool are allowed/you have access to?

Comment: If you take `seconds.microsecond` as a floating point number you can spare the first two steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with `awk`, then you can use this script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN{ FS="[\\[\\]\\|]+" }
     { printf("[%s]%011.6f|%s\n", $2,$3-prev,$4)
       prev = $3 }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`

The first line setups the fieldsplitting to use the brackets and pipe (ignore the backslashes they are need to escape the symbols that are regexp metacharacters). The second line prints the fields and calculates the timediff. The last line stores the current time for the calculation in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with a `bash` script. Since bash lacks floating point arithmetic, we have to gather seconds and microseconds seperately (or call an external tool like `bc` for each line):

**script.sh**

```
IFS='|[].'

factor=1000000
prev=0
while read dummy pid secs msecs text;
do
    msecs=$(( $secs * $factor + $msecs ))
    timediff=$(( $msecs - $prev ))
    prev=$msecs
    secs=$(( $timediff / $factor ))
    msecs=$(( $timediff - $secs * $factor ))

    printf "[%s]%04d.%06d|%s\n" "$pid" "$secs" "$msecs" "$text"
done
```

Use it like this: `bash script.sh yourfile`